# Redirect Facebook AppCenter link to website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I share a link on the Facebook wall, it shows as "Person shared a product on Website Name". The "Website Name" part redirects to something like https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/?app_id=328091087287454 (not my website, just a sample).

Is there any way to redirect the person to the actual website when they click that link? It seems a waste to redirect someone to a Facebook AppCenter URL when there's really nothing there, as it's not a real web-app, just used to share links.

I already set the website in the App Configuration to http://www.url.com/ and https://www.url.com/ but it's not working, still.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you share a link via an application the post is associated with that specific application. The name of the application will always direct users to the actual application - there is nothing you can do about this.

What you might be able to do, if your Facebook application doesn't actually have content, is perform a JavaScript redirect as soon as a user lands on your application. Something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  top.location.href = "http://your-cool-website.com";
</script>
```

Anyone visiting your application from clicking on the link in the post (or actually any visitor) will be directed to `http://your-cool-website.com`.

Keep in mind that Facebook doesn't approve of these "no content" applications and should they detect this, they very well might take action against your application and possibly even your personal account.

Comment: Thank you very much for that :) I wouldn't want to risk the account, so I will not do that, but strangely the page https://www.facebook.com/neowin for example and their website, when they share something it is posted as "shared a link on Neowin" and the name Neowin does redirect to their website. I have no idea how they do it, though.

Comment: @user1227914 - I don't exactly see what you're talking about. Where can I see a post with that text?